# Angular $scope is setting value first than service, after second function call everything fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to set data to controller using my service viewShare, when i look to my console i can see the console.log of controller coming first and undefined but the services started first the strange is after this console.log, i can see the console.log from viewShare populated. If i try the function in controller again then my controller is populated correctly.

my controller:

```
$scope.getLine = function(search){
 arcTouchAPI.getLine(search);
 console.log(viewShare.getDetails);

 $scope.details = viewShare.getDetails.details;  //angular ignores my viewShare call and go to console.log($scope.details) than it start the viewShare service
 $scope.$apply;
 console.log($scope.details);

};
```

my service API:

```
var _getLine = function(search){


var encoded = $base64.encode("xxxx:xxxx");
$http({
  url: "https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run",
  headers : {
    "X-AppGlu-Environment":"xxxx",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+encoded,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  data: { 
    "params":{
      "stopName": "%"+search+"%"
    }
  }
}).then(function(response){ 
    viewShare.add(response.data.rows);
   // console.log($rootScope.details + "details");
   console.log(response.data.rows);


});



}
 return {
 getLine : _getLine
}

});
```

my service to share data between views:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('viewShare', function viewShare() { 
var messages={};


var _add = function(message){
  messages.details = "";
  messages.details=message;
  console.log(messages.details);
  return messages.details;
};


var  _getDetails = function(){

  return messages;

 };

 return{
    getDetails: messages,
    add: _add

}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` call is non-blocking, which means that your `console.log` is executed straight after your request is sent to `getLine` (as coded), however this does not wait for the `$http` call to finish, and therefore has no data right away. You should return the `$http` promise from `_getLine`, and wait for the promise to resolve, before trying to `getDetails`. Furthermore, an explicit call to `$scope.$apply` is not necessary.

```
var _getLine = function(search){
var encoded = $base64.encode("xxxx:xxxx");
  return $http({ // add return statement here to return a promise
    url: "https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run",
    headers : {
      "X-AppGlu-Environment":"xxxx",
      "Authorization": "Basic "+encoded,
      "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: { 
      "params":{
        "stopName": "%"+search+"%"
      }
    }
  }).then(function(response){ 
    viewShare.add(response.data.rows);
    // console.log($rootScope.details + "details");
    console.log(response.data.rows);
  });
}
```

Change controller to:

```
$scope.getLine = function(search){
 arcTouchAPI.getLine(search).then(function(){
      console.log(viewShare.getDetails);
      $scope.details = viewShare.getDetails.details; 
 });

};
```